# solr search syntax : search document when array contains "all" values in search string

Tags: search, database-design, solr

I am trying to put together a search solution where i control the document structure as well as the search string pattern. The need is to be able to search/select documents

```
{
    "type" : "planet",
    "name" : [ "earth","mars","venus","jupiter" ]
}

{
    "type" : "planet",
    "name" : [  "earth","saturn","jupiter" ]
}
```

where the values in array meet all or one of the search strings ->

`search: "Earth or Mars"` should match `a:["earth","mars","venus","jupiter"]`

`search : "Earth and Mars"` should match 
 `a:["earth","mars","venus","jupiter"]` but not 
`a:["earth","venus","jupiter"]`

I can restructure the document schema, if need be, though I want to reduce denormalization - since my actual dataset spans in billions of rows - and denormalization will just increase the size of overall indexed dataset.

As it is, the search is behaving relatively erratically, the AND is honored, but OR is not. I m concerned that its due to the fact that the content for search target is inside an array element (which is defined as a Multivalued item)

Any thoughts / ideas ?

Comment: `q:op=AND` and querying against the `search`/`a` field should behave as you want by default

Comment: `or` in your example inside a string will be considered as part of the string, NOT as an operator. In that case you'd have to do `search:(Earth OR Mars)`, or `search:Earth OR search:Mars` - or `q.op=OR&q=earth mars&defType=edismax`